# Multiple image uploads using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code, I have multiple input fields, so I want to upload images after submit, but in this way only second image is getting uploaded.

**Form page**

```
<script>
    function sendimg() {
        alert("ok");
        var newname = $('#txtname').val();
        var file_data1 = $('#inputfile1').prop('files')[0];
        var file_data2 = $('#inputfile2').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();                     // Create a form
        form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data1);
        form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data2);

        $.ajax({
            url: "img2.php",
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {form_data, name:newname},
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type='file' name='inputfile[]' id='inputfile1'>
<input type='file' name='inputfile[]' id='inputfile2'>
<input class="button" type="button" id="post_ad_btn" name="post_ad_btn"  value="POST AD" onclick="sendimg();">
```

**upload.php**

```
$src = $_FILES['inputfile'][0]['tmp_name'];
$targ = "../".$_FILES['inputfile'][0]['name'];
move_uploaded_file($src, $targ);

$src = $_FILES['inputfile'][1]['tmp_name'];
$targ = "../".$_FILES['inputfile'][1]['name'];
move_uploaded_file($src, $targ);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        form_data.append('inputfile', file_data1);
        form_data.append('inputfile', file_data2);
```

You're overwriting the old value. To send an array to PHP via POST, you need to append `[]` to the end of the input name, and things are a little more complicated when dealing with arrays so your best bet is just to serialize the form by passing it to the `FormData` constructor. While you're at it, may as well use proper jQuery event binding.

```
<form>
    <input type='file' name='inputfile[]' id='inputfile1'>
    <input type='file' name='inputfile[]' id='inputfile2'>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="post_ad_btn" name="post_ad_btn"  value="POST AD">
</form>

<script>
    $("#post_ad_btn").on("click", function (e) {
        alert("ok");
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        var form_data = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you help me looping the array in upload process while storing the images.

Comment: how can i send another text string along with it. see my chnaged code.

Answer (score 1):

The `inputfile` field has to appear as an array to PHP like so:

```
form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data1);
form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data2);
```

Check the third example here [FormData.append() @ MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Answer (score 1):

Is not it because of the append's name is the same? If you want an array, I believe the correct one would be to put [].

form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data1);
 form_data.append('inputfile[]', file_data2);